# operator << interprets arithmetic operation if the result is unsigned int or unsigned short

Tags: c++, unsigned, short

I use gcc 4.8.3 under  fedora 19 64bits

```
unsigned u1=10, u2=42;
unsigned short us1=10, us2=42;

int main() {
   cout << "u1-u2="<<u1-u2<<", us1-us2="<<us1-us2<<endl;
}
```

Result : 
u1-u2=4294967264, us1-us2=-32

The << operator seems to interpret the result of the second operation as a **signed** short
whereas it interprets the result of the first operation as an **unsigned** int

Answer (score 5):

As operands of `-` and most other arithmetic operators, any values of integral type narrower than `int` are promoted to `int`.

So `us1 - us2` behaves as `(int)us1 - (int)us2`.

This rule is pretty annoying in modern C++, but it came in right from the earliest version of C (because int-sized registers were used for arithmetic) and it would break too much code to change it now.

Comment: thank you very much
One roundabout would be I suppose to cast to unsigned like so
    cout << "u1-u2="<<u1-u2<<",(unsigned )us1-us2="<<us1-us2<<endl;

Comment: Use `static_cast` as a type safe way of casting in C++.

Comment: Soryy
One roundabout could be I suppose :

     unsigned short us1=10, us2=42, us3=us1-us2;
     cout << "u1-u2="<<u1-u2<<", us1-us2="<<us3<<endl;